# Key command for opening VSCode class/function dropdown window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

When I click to the right of the filename in VSCode I see a dropdown window that allows me to quickly jump to various functions and classes within the current file.

[image: Window]

Is there a key command that opens this dropdown window in MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu is called Breadcrumbs. The keyboard command to open on MacOS is:

Cmd + Shift + .

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_breadcrumb-keyboard-navigation